# How we can use mutimap_agg function in spark sql and also suggest if any equivalent or alternative function to this

Tags: sql, dataframe, function, apache-spark, pyspark

Can anyone help how multimap_agg function in SQL and  can be used in spark sql

Answer (score 0):

multimap_agg function doesn't exist in spark-sql at least on version 3.2.1

Reference:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions.html